# ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser variable list

Tags: winapi, environment-variables

Where I can get the full list of variables, replaced by the WinAPI function?

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains only a single example: `%USERPROFILE%`.

Is this list full and correct? http://www.rapidee.com/en/environment-variables

Comment: The list is editable by the user. Open a dos prompt, type `set` and press return to see them.

Comment: If you need to know, you are doing it wrong. What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm working on an autocomplete system for a special config editor. It offers variants as you type %. The config file entries should be valid for expanding on a 'clear' Windows machine. The table I found made me think it's a good idea to show the administrator in a tooltip, what Windows version is required for every variable and how it's expanded there.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`GetEnvironmentStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187.aspx) to find out the environment for your process, at the point when you make the call. You will need to parse the double null-terminated string that is returned to find the name/value pairs.

Note that there is no single definitive list of environment variables. Each process maintains its own private environment. The environment is specified when the process is created. Typically it inherits from the environment of the parent process. But not always. It is perfectly possible, and normal, for the parent process to specify an environment for the child process that differs from its own.

Note also that the environment can change during the lifetime of the process. Calls made to [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206.aspx) will modify the environment of the calling process.

You should be able to deduce by now that the list of variables in your link may or may not be found in an environment. An environment could contain all of those variables, or none of them. It could contain variables not found in that list. It could contain no variables at all.

Learn more about environment variables here: [Environment Variables (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, the editor I'm working on (please look at my answer to IInspectable), runs under LAMP and Windows calls are impossible there. I see now, I should ask instead what is the list for expanding by the function on an out-of-the-box fresh Windows machine. (And, maybe, the list will vary slightly depending on Windows versions).

Comment: Your question was tagged winapi which implies the use of the Windows API. Hence this answer.

Comment: It's tagged so because the function I asked about belongs to WinAPI. I just cannot use ANOTHER WinAPI function to predict the first one behavior.

Comment: Given that your programming environment is not mentioned in the question, or indeed in any of the comments, and the question was tagged winapi, I think this answer is reasonable. With your rep you ought to know how the site works now. Did I really not answer the question you asked?